# How do you stop an in-game mouse cursor switching to the OS's default cursor?

Tags: macos, bug, games, cursor

For years now I have known that, when playing Rimworld on my computer, the in-game cursor will switch to the OS's cursor for no apparent reason. I had thought this was a bug exclusive to Rimworld and left it at that, but I have just found the same thing happening in a completely different game (Victoria 3). Here are pictures of what I mean (in Victoria 3):

[image: In-game cursor] [image: OS cursor]

In case it is not clear in the images (unfortunately I had to take those pictures with my phone, as the screenshot function on Mac seems to add the cursor 'in post'), the in-game cursor is actually larger than the OS's cursor, which means it is not a bleed-through or layer issue. That is also the case in Rimworld.

As far as I am aware, the games have almost nothing in common: Victoria 3 is ARM-native, Rimworld runs through Rosetta; Victoria 3 uses on the Clausewitz engine, Rimworld uses Unity; the devs are entirely separate, etc. Basically, there is no overlap which might suggest that it is a game-specific problem. The only other possibilities are that it is an OS or Steam related bug.

I have not been able to find any other mention of this happening to other people; however, that could be because searching for questions involving 'default cursors' mostly leads to results about changing the default cursor design or people having issues with jittery cursors.

I am entirely at a loss about what the problem might be. Has anyone else come across this issue before? If so, does anyone have any idea what might cause this, or how I might stop it from happening?